# Is iptables-save and iptables-restore works if I am using firewalld?

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, docker, firewalld

We are using docker-compose to run our services and firewalld as our firewall. Now we need to modify some firewall rules, but since firewalld has possible risk that [remove DOCKER-USER iptables chain when reloading](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35043) and I don't want to restart the docker daemon, I am considering using iptables-save to export the rules, manually editing the rules and then using iptables-restore to restore it. If I am correct, firewalld is just a management tool of iptables, so this should be work. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried, and when I use `firewall-cmd --get-active-zones`, I can not see the changes I made for the iptables exported rules ... so I think this may not gonna work

Comment: Are you using a recent version of docker? It should already work properly with firewalld.